# Simple git merge conflict using VScode error

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, merge

I'm trying to merge two branches (let's say branchA and branchB) of a simple README.md that contains some generic text using VScode. I've looked at many youtube videos/resources, and it seems a codelens pop-up occurs for merges that lets you see the conflict and make changes before committing. Prompts you to accept changes, allows you to compare, shows them together above and below, etc... However, on my end, when I perform "git merge branchB" to merge with branchA, in the terminal, I'm greeted with:

> warning: Cannot merge binary files: README.md (HEAD vs. featureB)
> Auto-merging README.md CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in README.md
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

I still see just branchA. Nothing happens in my VScode editor, other than the folder/file information in the sidebar and title in the editor UI being highlighted in red. I'm unable to see the two branches next to each other in the editor to resolve the merge/conflict. I suspect this is because of "warning: Cannot merge binary files: README.md (HEAD vs. featureB)" but I'm not merging binary files, just a .md. For good measure, I tried this same merge with a README.txt and was greeted by the same error. To make sure it wasn't my local machine or install of VScode, I installed both programs on an old laptop and ran into the same error -- I'm unable to see the conflict via codelens, I'm just seeing branch X.

When I look up online resources, this is what is seemingly supposed to pop up after a merge conflict in VScode (taken from a youtube video showcase):
[correct merge conflict pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktKYr.png)

My issue, is that for me, this type of editor pop-up does not occur. For me, it would simply still just show the HEAD text in the editor while the title of the file and the sidebar title of the folder/file become red. Under the Source Control tab it does say Source Control > Merge branch 'branchB' into branchA. But again, nothing indicates how I can see both branches and Accept/Compare changes akin to the screenshot.

Comment: What does `git check-attr -a README.md` and `git ls-files --eol README.md` report?